# Can't compile a javaFX project with Gluon and mariadb jdbc

Tags: maven, javafx, jdbc, mariadb, gluon

I'm trying to write a JavaFX application which connects to a mariaDB database with jdbc. I use Gluon Client plugin for maven.
The compilation fails and I obtain several errors, all similars to the following :

```
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Warning: Aborting stand-alone image build. Unsupported features in 5 methods
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Detailed message:
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: org.mariadb.jdbc.credential.aws.AwsCredentialGenerator.getToken(). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Trace: 
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB]   at parsing org.mariadb.jdbc.credential.aws.AwsIamCredentialPlugin.get(AwsIamCredentialPlugin.java:97)
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Call path from entry point to org.mariadb.jdbc.credential.aws.AwsIamCredentialPlugin.get(): 
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB]   at org.mariadb.jdbc.credential.aws.AwsIamCredentialPlugin.get(AwsIamCredentialPlugin.java:92)
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB]   at org.mariadb.jdbc.credential.aws.AwsIamCredentialPlugin.get(AwsIamCredentialPlugin.java:50)
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.SystemPropertiesSupport.initializeLazyValue(SystemPropertiesSupport.java:216)
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.SystemPropertiesSupport.getProperty(SystemPropertiesSupport.java:169)
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.Target_java_lang_System.getProperty(JavaLangSubstitutions.java:291)
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST:Ljava_lang_System_2_0002egetProperty_00028Ljava_lang_String_2_00029Ljava_lang_String_2(generated:0)
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: com.sun.jna.Platform. To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing type is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Trace: 
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB]   at parsing org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.send.authentication.gssapi.GssUtility.getAuthenticationMethod(GssUtility.java:69)
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Call path from entry point to org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.send.authentication.gssapi.GssUtility.getAuthenticationMethod(): 
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB]   no path found from entry point to target method
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] 
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: com.sun.jna.Platform. To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing type is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Trace: 
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB]   at parsing org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.socket.SocketUtility.getSocketHandler(SocketUtility.java:71)
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Call path from entry point to org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.socket.SocketUtility.getSocketHandler(): 
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB]   no path found from entry point to target method
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] 
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: com.sun.jna.Platform. To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing type is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Trace: 
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB]   at parsing org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.pid.JnaPidFactory.<clinit>(JnaPidFactory.java:66)
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Call path from entry point to org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.pid.JnaPidFactory.<clinit>(): 
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB]   no path found from entry point to target method
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] 
[sam. mai 29 18:05:20 CEST 2021][INFOS] [SUB] Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory. To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing type is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
```

I didn't find any solution to this problem, does anybody have an idea ?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion? Add `--allow-incomplete-classpath` to `nativeImageArgs` in the plugin's [configuration](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_nativeimageargs).

Comment: Actually, I didn't know what to do with this suggestion... Thanks a lot for the precision about ```nativeImageArgs``` !

I can compile now but linking fails, I get : 

`undefined reference to « JNI_OnLoad_jaas »`

`undefined reference to « Java_com_sun_security_auth_module_UnixSystem_getUnixInfo »`

Comment: The plugin doesn't add `libjaas.a` to the link phase (yet), so for now you might need to do it manually. The `process-link.....log` file contains the exact command that you need to use, copy it, paste it to your terminal and add `-ljaas` to it (right after `-lsunec` for instance).

Comment: Thank you very much ! Everything works now.   
(By the way, there is no problem when I use android profile, libjaas.a is added automatically)